# rotate animation board (python, pygame)

Tags: python, pygame

This is more of a conceptual question:
If I want to rotate an entire playing board (a chess board for example) by 90 degrees, am I better off rotating the individual fields of the board around its center point individually, or is there a way for me to take a 'screenshot' of the field and rotate that as a single picture? I would have the code rotate the actual values of the board separately from the animation (once the animation was done, I would just redraw the screen with everything now in the right positions).

I hope my question is understandable. I have just started programming in python a couple of days ago and have so far only done text based games, but want to move onto GUI based games,

thank you in advance, your help is very much appreciated,
keelboat

Answer (score 2):

You should rotate the board completely.
Taking a screenshot, and rotating that would be almost as taxing as just rotating the objects of the chessboard. Batching the objects and rotate them would be a solution.

Edit: i just realized that Pygame is one of the few libraries that might miss batched rendering. Pygame is nice, for a started learning curve but you're better off with other libraries (this is just a friendly suggestion)

## Friendly suggestion

---

I'd go with Pyglet if I really wanted to do some cool stuff (including game development of your scale).
It's cross-platform, doesn't depend on Python version in the sense that all the others do and you get a direct hook to the OpenGL library making it redicilously fast. And it's quite easy to use actually.

Here's and example of drag and drop:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pyglet
from time import time, sleep

class Window(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self, refreshrate):
        super(Window, self).__init__(vsync = False)
        self.frames = 0
        self.framerate = pyglet.text.Label(text='Unknown', font_name='Verdana', font_size=8, x=10, y=10, color=(255,255,255,255))
        self.last = time()
        self.alive = 1
        self.refreshrate = refreshrate
        self.click = None
        self.drag = False

    def on_draw(self):
        self.render()

    def on_mouse_press(self, x, y, button, modifiers):
        self.click = x,y

    def on_mouse_drag(self, x, y, dx, dy, buttons, modifiers):
        if self.click:
            self.drag = True
            print 'Drag offset:',(dx,dy)

    def on_mouse_release(self, x, y, button, modifiers):
        if not self.drag and self.click:
            print 'You clicked here', self.click, 'Relese point:',(x,y)
        else:
            print 'You draged from', self.click, 'to:',(x,y)
        self.click = None
        self.drag = False

    def render(self):
        self.clear()
        if time() - self.last >= 1:
            self.framerate.text = str(self.frames)
            self.frames = 0
            self.last = time()
        else:
            self.frames += 1
        self.framerate.draw()
        self.flip()

    def on_close(self):
        self.alive = 0

    def run(self):
        while self.alive:
            self.render()
            # ----> Note: <----
            #  Without self.dispatc_events() the screen will freeze
            #  due to the fact that i don't call pyglet.app.run(),
            #  because i like to have the control when and what locks
            #  the application, since pyglet.app.run() is a locking call.
            event = self.dispatch_events()
            sleep(1.0/self.refreshrate)

win = Window(23) # set the fps
win.run()
```

Pyglet also enables you to do batched rendering (meaning you can send instructions to the GPU in a large chunk instead of item-per-item which makes it easy to make complex tasks quick and painless.. also you can do `batch.rotate(90)` and you're all done)

Comment: If you really want to switch from pygame to pyglet, I would suggest using cocos2d instead of pure pyglet.

Comment: Sure, you can. But note that you'll go away from the "flexebility" of pure pyglet code and add more dependencies. Before you use cocos2d you should ask yourself if you'll ever want to build beyond this project. If not, then go for cocos2d if you want to get a quick fix :) (cocos2d is a neat project btw)

Comment: *cocos2d is a neat project*: That's way understated :-)

Answer (score 1):

In Pygame you have a surface that is created when you initialize and configure your display.  Often, people will blit other images directly to this surface, then update the display to render the image to the screen, but there's no reason why you can't create another surface to draw to, which can then be rotated and drawn to the surface rendered by the display.

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
middle_man = pygame.Surface((500,500))

# draw stuff to middle_man here
....

# rotate middle_man
# note that this creates a padded surface if not rotating in 90 degree increments
rotated_middle_man = pygame.transform.rotate(middle_man, 45.0)

# draw middle_man back to the screen surface
crop_rect = pygame.Rect(rotated_middle_man.get_width() / 2 - screen.get_width() / 2,
                        rotated_middle_man.get_height() / 2 - screen.get_height() / 2,
                        screen.get_width(), screen.get_height())
screen.blit(rotated_middle_man, (0,0), crop_rect)

# update the screen
pygame.display.update()
```